# Basic matrix calculation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Variables:

```
y_hat = pd.DataFrame([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5])
y_actual = pd.DataFrame(Macro.iloc[8:13,1:2])
```

I have a pandas dataframe `y_hat`:

```
y_hat 
Out[24]: 
            0
0  409.612553
1  573.936775
2  256.213344
3  136.219153
4  419.977863
```

I have a pandas dataframe `y_actual`:

```
y_actual
Out[25]: 
         y
8   422.40
9   580.42
10  256.76
11  128.96
12  445.42
```

I am essentially trying to calculate a MAPE (mean average percentage error) between y_actual and y_hat.  The R code would look something like:

```
MAPE = colmeans(abs((y_hat - y_actual)/y_actual)*100)
```

However in Python, I can't even get past the first step `y_hat - y_actual`, as it returns error:

```
y_hat - y_actual
Out[29]: 
     0   y
0  NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN
4  NaN NaN
8  NaN NaN
9  NaN NaN
10 NaN NaN
11 NaN NaN
12 NaN NaN
```

Can I run this calc using Pandas dataframes?  Is there a Python function equivalent to colmeans (mean of column)?

Comment: In Pandas, you'll have to align the index (the first column) to make that work.

Comment: And the column name too, judging by the output

Comment: Thanks - to create the y_actual variable, I'm using y_actual = pd.DataFrame(Macro.iloc[8:13,1:2]).  Why doesn't y_actual just restart at a new index (why is it preserving the legacy index, which is just from a csv file).

Comment: May be `print(y_hat.values - y_actual.values)`

Comment: @ZJAY because that's basically the whole point of pandas.

Comment: May be you can try something like `print(np.mean(np.abs((y_actual.values - y_hat.values) / y_actual.values)) * 100)` where `no` means `numpy` as you can use `import numpy as np`

Comment: thanks @student - you are more than a student, a teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as following with similar approach in other [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/mean-absolute-percentage-error-mape-in-scikit-learn):

```
import numpy as np

print(np.mean(np.abs((y_actual.values - y_hat.values) / y_actual.values)) * 100)
```